# Cannot use immutable DTO in Spock test

Tags: java, groovy, spock, dto, lombok

I have immutable DTO

```
@Value
@Builder
public class UserDto {

    Long id;
    String username;
}
```

`@Value` annotations comes from [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value).
It marks all fields as `private` and `final`. Moreover class is also marked as `final` and `equals()` `hashCode()` and `toString()` methods are generated. I found it very convenient when implementing *data transfer objects*

The problem begun while writing test using [spock framework](http://spockframework.org). 
When inside the test I try to mock some behaviour:

```
userFactory.create(userDto) >> user
```

exception is thrown:

```
org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock for class user.dto.UserDto because Java mocks cannot mock final classes.
```

Is there any solution to these in `Spock` framework or in any other way? I'm really sticked to `@Value` annotation and I don't want to remove it.

Comment: It's quite hard to mock `final` classes. probably powerMock can to it. btw, why do you want to mock a POJO? You can just create a test instance

Comment: I do not want to mock POJO. I want to mock behaviour of UserFactory. I created User and UserDto "by hand". But in spite of this, Spock mocks these objects while used as mocking arguments and returned objects

Comment: How about an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I did not understand your previous comment at all. Let the code speak. BTW, I agree with _dehasi_: Either make the class non-final you you can create a subclass mocking it or if it is just a DTO like in this case, don't mock it at all because there is no need to as it has no behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok `@NonFinal` annotation can be used above the class, to mark this class as **non** `final`. Then immutable DTO can be created very easily and there is no problem with mocking.